# Migrations are pending; run 'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

After this error in my web page when i have run `> rake db:migrate`. It shows error such as:

`rake aborted!`

`you have already activated rake 10.1.1 but you gemfile requires rake 10.1.0 using bundle exec may solve this.`

- when i tried with `bundle exec rake db:migrate` **it works.**
- And when i tried with the `rake db:migrate`. **i shows error**

My question is:

- What is the difference between `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and `rake db:migrate`.
- every time i have to do like this **if yes then why?**
- What is the problem in my project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bundle exec rake db:migrate` will run `rake db:migrate` with the environment of your Gemfile.

You have an error because your Gemfile requires a version of rake but you have a newer one installed on your system.

By default, `rake` will run the latest available version, hence the mismatch.

You should always prefix your commands with bundle exec inside a project managed by bundler, I personally alias `bx` to `bundle exec`.

You can also use [binstubs](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/use-bundlers-binstubs)

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `bundle update`.

It seems, that your Gemfile.lock is out of sync with your Gemfile.